# Visualize Cumulative column data in Google Studio

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets, looker-studio

I have data in CSV as follows

| State | Cumulative Number of cases | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | 0 | 12-Feb-2021 |
| India | 2 | 13-Feb-2021 |
| India | 5 | 14-Feb-2021 |
| India | 8 | 15-Feb-2021 |
| India | 17 | 16-Feb-2021 |
| India | 39 | 17-Feb-2021 |

I want to un-accumulate 'Number of cases' to visualize line chart using Google Studio. X-axis will be 'Date' and Y-axis will be 'Number of cases'.

When I am currently creating line chart with 'SUM' as metric, it just adds us cumulative numbers which is not correct. For example, at 14-Feb-2021, point gets plotted as 7 which sum of of 0+2+5. Ideally I want incremental value to be plotted. Hence for 14-Feb-2021, difference between 13-Feb and 14-Feb as point, which is 3.
Can anyone please share how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that it can be achieved is by:

- ***Chart***: [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697)
- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Breakdown Dimension***: `State`
- ***Metric***: `Cumulative Number of cases`; ***Running Calculation***: Running Delta

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/01e5a1fd-aaea-47ea-b2ab-16a0305b127d) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgz1xXdILmjzziGVS28kQ30Y6gB5HbesoXS19XQiInQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]